# Can't get mark using "index" in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone answer why in the code below the command `self.text.mark_previous(self.text.index("insert"))` works and returns the correct mark but `self.text.mark_previous("insert")` returns `tk::anchor1` instead? Just click on an area in the text and hit the button.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.text = tk.Text()
        self.text.pack()
        self.strings = ["Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3"]
        for text in self.strings:
            self.text.mark_set(text, "insert")
            self.text.mark_gravity(text, "left")
            self.text.insert("insert", "{}\n".format(text))
        for mark in self.strings:
            print(self.text.index(mark))
        self.button = tk.Button(text="Find Region", command=self.find_region)
        self.button.pack()

    def find_region(self):
        self.text.update_idletasks()
        region = self.text.mark_previous("insert") # This doesn't work. It returns tk::anchor1
        region2 = self.text.mark_previous(self.text.index("insert")) # This works
        print("You are in region {} {}".format(region, region2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that tkinter doesn't consider `"insert"` and `index("insert")` as *precisely* the same thing when dealing with marks. They are the same from the perspective of *just* the text, but not from the perspective of all of the other data managed by the text widget.

Consider a text widget with the text "Hello, world" at line 1. When you click on the letter "w", a couple of things happen: tkinter will add the marks "insert", "tk::anchor1", and "current". These marks are ordered. If we were to convert the text widget contents to xml it might look something like this:

```
<text index='1.0'>Hello, </text>
<mark index='1.7' id='current'/>
<mark index='1.7' id='tk::anchor1'/>
<mark index='1.7' id='insert'/>
<text index='1.7'>world</text>
```

When calling `mark_previous("1.7")`, the index "1.7" refers to the point immediately before the letter "w" and *after* all of the marks. Thus, when you ask for the previous mark, it's going to return "insert" since that is what is immediately to the left of the letter "w". However, if you ask for the mark previous to "insert" rather than "1.7", you're going to get "tk::anchor1" since that is the mark immediately to the left of the "insert" mark.

You can see the order of marks and data by using the text widget `dump` method. It returns information as a list rather than xml, but it lets you see the internal structure of the document.

Continuing with the same example ("Hello, world", after clicking before the "w"), the `dump` method returns the following (I've added newlines for clarity):

```
[
   ('text', 'Hello, ', '1.0'), 
   ('mark', 'current', '1.7'), 
   ('mark', 'tk::anchor1', '1.7'), 
   ('mark', 'insert', '1.7'), 
   ('text', 'world\n', '1.7')
]
```

As you can see, the mark "current" comes before the mark "tk::anchor1", which comes before the mark "insert", which comes before the letter "w" in "world".

Comment: Is there a way to find out the number in the `"tk::anchor#"` mark name given a text widget? I have a weird interaction between `idlelib`'s `Redirector` and my code which blocks all mouse events and there is a bug if `"tk::anchor#"` isn't set. I have multiple text widgets and I'd like to avoid a for loop setting all possible numbers for `"tk::anchor#"` marks.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I do not know.

Comment: Final question, is there a way to remove all `tk` bindings to a text widget? Just binding and returning `"break"` can mess with `tk`'s internal state especially the mouse events.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, you can remove “Text” from the list of binding tags for the widget.

Answer (score 2):

### Because there is a mark `tk::anchor#` at the same index as `insert`, but on previous position.

Initially or whenever the mouse pointer is not on any text, `current` and `insert` mark are at the same index and in the sequence of `current` followed by `insert`.

So if you click on your button "Find Region" at the start of program it will print,

```
You are in region current Region 3
```

because by sequence, `current` mark is at previous position to `insert` mark(but at same index), but `Region 3` mark is at previous "**index**" to `insert` mark.

From what I understand, tkinter adds an extra mark `tk::anchor#` when you click in the textbox for first time(I don't know reason yet), which is at the same index as `insert`  but right before `insert` mark(and after `current` if mouse pointer not on text).

*So when you search for previous mark based on name of mark and not index, then the previous mark on the same index will be returned. You can test it yourself by adding two user defined marks at the same index.*

Comment: Right but why does previous_mark("insert") and previous_mark(text.index("insert")) return different marks?

Comment: When you pass a mark to function `previous_mark` it looks at the sequence of marks, and returns the mark at position previous to the mark passed as argument. But when you pass index to function `previous_mark` it will not consider a mark with same index as previous mark. So `previous_mark("insert")` returns a mark on previous position to `insert` but at same index(if available), but `previous_mark(text.index("insert"))` returns a mark which is on a previous index to `insert`(even if another mark is available previous to `insert` on same index).